# Is sharing data with initializer list out-scoped valid in standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

> `lst2 = lst` Copying or assigning an initializer_list does not copy the elements in the list. After the copy, the original and the copy share the elements.

According to C++ Primer Table 6.1, assign one initializer list will share the data, but what if the initializer list share with an other out-scoped, for example, the code below is a part of a function

```
std::initializer_list<int> lst1;
{
    std::initializer_list<int> lst2 = {1, 2, 3};
    lst1 = lst2;
}
```

it seems initializer lists may share the literal's data, but what is the lifetime of the array literal specified in the standard? is this code safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not seem valid. Here is some relevant extract from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

> The underlying array is a temporary array of type const T[N], in which
> each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions
> are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original
> initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as
> any other temporary object, except that initializing an
> initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the
> array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same
> exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member).

After you exit your inner scope, the temporary underlying array is going to be destroyed - as lifetime of inner `lst2` ends - and `lst1` from enclosing scope will end up with dangling pointers.